# Can I not use more than one NavDropdown?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have the following code nested within my Navbar :

```
<Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect fixedTop fluid>
  <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Nav onSelect={this.props.onSelect} pullRight>
      <NavItem eventKey={'navItem1'}>NavItem 1</NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={'navItem2'}>NavItem 2</NavItem>

      <NavDropdown eventKey={'dropdown1'} title="Dropdown1" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
        <MenuItem eventKey={'placeholder1'}>Placeholder</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem divider />
        <MenuItem eventKey={'placeholder2'}>Placeholder</MenuItem>
      </NavDropdown>

      <NavDropdown eventKey={'dropdown2'} title="Dropdown2" id="basic-nav-dropdown-2">
        <MenuItem eventKey={'placeholder3'}>Placeholder</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem divider />
        <MenuItem eventKey={'placeholder4'}>Placeholder</MenuItem>
      </NavDropdown>

      <NavDropdown eventKey={'dropdown3'} title="DropDown3" id="basic-nav-dropdown-3">
        <MenuItem eventKey={'placeholder5'}>Placeholder</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem divider />
        <MenuItem eventKey={'placeholder6'}>Placeholder</MenuItem>
      </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

The problem I am facing is that only Dropdown1 shows the dropdown. When looking at the issue using my ChromeTools, it seems that the other two dropdowns are not having the "open" class added to them.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Your NavDropdown components themselves don't have event keys, they just have a title and an id value. It should be like this:

```
  <NavItem eventKey={1}>NavItem 1</NavItem>
  <NavItem eventKey={2}>NavItem 2</NavItem>

  <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown1" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
    <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Placeholder</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem divider />
    <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Placeholder</MenuItem>
  </NavDropdown>

  <NavDropdown eventKey={4} title="Dropdown2" id="basic-nav-dropdown-2">
    <MenuItem eventKey={4.1}>Placeholder</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem divider />
    <MenuItem eventKey={4.2}>Placeholder</MenuItem>
  </NavDropdown>
```

Comment: In my not-psuedo code, I do have eventKeys and it is still not working. Good catch though, I will edit my question.

Comment: I just tested your code and it works fine, I could see all 3 dropdown menus. I used some default `onSelect` function that just logs to console. Do you have the latest version of the React Bootstrap module and CSS files? DO you get any console errors when trying to open a dropdown menu? And what does your onSelect property function do?